# Navigating through Views wth ViewNavigatorApplication on Flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4

I am working on a `ViewNavigatorApplication` with Flex and I am trying to figure out how to properly work with the `navigator`.

My problem is that, if you have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                            firstView="views.IntroView">

    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button label="Home" click="navigator.popToFirstView()"/>
        <s:Button label="Start" click="navigator.pushView(StartView)"/>
    </s:navigationContent>
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

and press on the `Start` button multiple times, multiple instances of `StartView` are created, which is reasonable since this is more or less a stack of views. You can confirm that by hitting the back button of the mobile device.

Is there a way to easily avoid this, or do i have to code a (quite complex) 'controller' that keeps track of stuff and makes sure that only one instance of each view can be pushed, `popView()`'s where needed and whatnot.

I cannot seem to find any documentation on that, but if I missed something, please share it with me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your `StartView` class extends the `View` class, you can set it's `destructionPolicy` property to "never". This will make the `ViewNavigator` re-use that particular view rather than creating a new one each time it's navigated to.

It's typical in Flex for things like this to be reused, but in mobile apps Adobe seems to have erred on the side of freeing up memory.

Comment: I will try this, I guess it should work. But even the documentation on destruction policies wouldn't mention that "never" means the ViewNavigator will re-use it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misread your question. Perhaps you can use the `ViewNavigator`'s  `activeView` property in your click handler and only push the StartView if `!(navigator.activeView is StartView)` or use that same logic to disable the button.